# Laravel Vue error when trying to use chart.js with Laravel-charts package

Tags: laravel, vue.js, chart.js

I'm using Laravel charts from https://charts.erik.cat/ and I noticed that I'm getting the error below.

I also noticed that the error disappears when I remove this line (related to rendering which I placed in the layout before yielding the content):
But when I do that, the charts don't work.

```
{!! $chart->script() !!}
```

In the content I placed:

```
{!! $chart->container() !!}
```

I'm guessing there is some conflict with app.js?

```
app.js:38309 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

191|  
192|          </main>
193|                    <script type="text/javascript">
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
194|      var ctvChart = document.getElementById('mzaqnvhkcsrjgeoxdwuipybtl').getContext('2d');
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
195|      function mzaqnvhkcsrjgeoxdwuipybtl_create(data) {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
196|          mzaqnvhkcsrjgeoxdwuipybtl_rendered = true;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
197|          document.getElementById("mzaqnvhkcsrjgeoxdwuipybtl_loader").style.display = 'none';
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
198|          document.getElementById("mzaqnvhkcsrjgeoxdwuipybtl").style.display = 'block';
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
199|          window.mzaqnvhkcsrjgeoxdwuipybtl = new Chart(document.getElementById("mzaqnvhkcsrjgeoxdwuipybtl").getContext("2d"), {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
.
.
.(...there is more)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving

```
{!! $chart->script() !!}
```

outside of the  tags in the layout.
I'm not sure why but it doesn't show that warning anymore.